# Showing custom notification in Community | Theme : Build your own || Custom apex notifications

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community, notification

I want to show custom notification through apex in the community. Community is having custom theme(all lightning components).

I know how to trigger apex custom notifications for the internal users. However, I am having trouble in replicating same for custom lightning component(and community of-course).

I checked `forceCommunity:notifications`, but it is only for the chatter related notifications, however we're not leveraging chatter &/or we need to have our own notifications generated by custom apex/PB/Flow.

Because for notification, I do not want to implement custom framework(which stores all notifications and renders in the community by custom CSS). I'm more inclined to avoid all CRUD operation/custom object/maintaining history and ownership constraints. If I can leverage existing notification that'd be great.

Is there any way to achieve the same?